# Imaginary Parts of Non-Trivial Riemann Zeroes

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, complex-numbers

### Introduction

According to the [Riemann Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis), all zeroes of the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) are either negative even integers (called *trivial zeroes*) or complex numbers of the form `1/2 ± i*t` for some real `t` value (called *non-trivial zeroes*). For this challenge, we will be considering only the non-trivial zeroes whose imaginary part is positive, and we will be assuming the Riemann Hypothesis is true. These non-trivial zeroes can be ordered by the magnitude of their imaginary parts. The first few are approximately `0.5 + 14.1347251i, 0.5 + 21.0220396i, 0.5 + 25.0108576i, 0.5 + 30.4248761i, 0.5 + 32.9350616i`.

### The Challenge

Given an integer `N`, output the imaginary part of the `N`th non-trivial zero of the Riemann zeta function, rounded to the nearest integer (rounded half-up, so `13.5` would round to `14`).

### Rules

- The input and output will be within the representable range of integers for your language.
- As previously stated, for the purposes of this challenge, the Riemann Hypothesis is assumed to be true.
- You may choose whether the input is zero-indexed or one-indexed.

### Test Cases

The following test cases are one-indexed.

```
1       14
2       21
3       25
4       30
5       33
6       38
7       41
8       43
9       48
10      50
50      143
100     237
```

### OEIS Entry

This is OEIS sequence [A002410](http://oeis.org/A002410).

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 23 bytes

```
⌊Im@ZetaZero@#+.5⌋&
```

Unfortunately, `Round` rounds `.5` to the nearest even number, so we have to implement rounding by adding `.5` and flooring.

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 25 bytes

There's not much support in GP for analytic number theory (it's mostly algebraic), but just enough for this challenge.

```
n->lfunzeros(1,15*n)[n]\/1
```

Answer (score 1):

### Sage, 34 bytes

```py
lambda n:round(lcalc.zeros(n)[-1])
```

[Try it online](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwNzDsKgDAQBcA-kDtsqfiURI0_8CRiET8BIa4SrTy9aaYcN3p7LpslHg5-E79avxbfHq4n4XTK9ZwVJpVCCncFYjqYJo0SFWoYNGjRoYdWMCqq5kEKojvEihjk4vEDYFUZ0w==&lang=sage)

This solution is a golfed form of the program found on the OEIS page.

`lcalc.zeros` is a function (which is thankfully spelled the shorter way, rather than `zeroes` for an extra byte) that returns the imaginary parts of the first `n` non-trivial Riemann zeta zeros. Taking the `-1`st index returns the `n`th zero (1-indexed), and `round` rounds it to the nearest integer. In Python 3, `round` uses banker's rounding (half-to-nearest-even), but thankfully Sage runs on Python 2, where `round` uses half-up rounding.